# Activity State not saved

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to save my Activity state while I swipe between activities but I cannot. Some things are saved and the others dont. I think it has to do somehow with the gestureListener I'm impementing but I'm not sure.

When I swipe to a different activity and then back to this one - the AsyncTask is still running and the Handler is still updating the GUI, however, the views I have displaying in this activity and the buttons are all in their initial configuration.

what am I doing wrong?

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        SimpleGestureListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    static String checkedIN = "";

    private int hoursSum;
    private int minutesSum;
    static int dayIs;
    static String madeSoFar = "";

    static int hoursCount = 0;
    static String formattedSeconds = "";
    static String formattedMinutes = "";
    public static NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
    static boolean killcheck = false;
    static String time = "";
    static Handler mHandler;

    private boolean clicked = false;
    private boolean wasShift = false;
    static String startString;
    static String finishString;
    private SimpleGestureFilter detector;
    private Typeface tf, tf2, roboto;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // **************** Set Fonts **************
        roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/robotothin.ttf");
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Advert.ttf");
        tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/passion.ttf");

        // **************** Gesture implementation ************

        detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this, this);

        // **************** Date and Time Objects *************

        final Date date = new Date();
        final Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        DateFormat DF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        final String DateInString = DF.format(today);
        String myString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date);
        final TextView dateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
        dateDisplay.setText(myString);

        final DBAdapter DB = new DBAdapter(this);

        // ************* Apply custom fonts ***************

        TextView Title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Title.setTypeface(tf);
        final TextView Author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        Author.setTypeface(roboto);
        TextView Current = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Current.setTypeface(roboto);
        DigitalClock DG = (DigitalClock) findViewById(R.id.digitalClock1);
        DG.setTypeface(roboto);
        TextView dater = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
        dater.setTypeface(roboto);
        TextView dateDisp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
        dateDisp.setTypeface(roboto);
        CheckedTextView CV = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        CV.setTypeface(roboto);

        // *************************************************//

        final Button checkIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CheckIn);
        checkIn.setTypeface(roboto);
        CheckedTextView check = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        Boolean enable = false;
        check.setEnabled(enable);

        mHandler = new Handler() {

            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                time = "Time: " + hoursCount + ":" + formattedMinutes + ":"
                        + formattedSeconds + " Money: " + madeSoFar;

                Author.setText(time);
            }
        };

        // **************** Click Listener for first Check In Button

        checkIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            int startHours;
            int startMinutes;
            int finishHours;
            int finishMinutes;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Check Out
                if (clicked == true) {
                    killcheck = true;
                    checkedIN = "Check In";
                    checkIn.setText(checkedIN);
                    finishHours = Utility.getHoursTime();
                    finishMinutes = Utility.getMinutesTime();
                    finishString = Integer.toString(Utility.getHoursTime())
                            + ":" + Integer.toString(Utility.getMinutesTime())
                            + " -";

                    clicked = false;
                    wasShift = true;

                    hoursSum = finishHours - startHours;
                    minutesSum = finishMinutes - startMinutes;

                    // Check In
                } else if (clicked == false) {
                    checkedIN = "Check Out";
                    checkIn.setText(checkedIN);
                    killcheck = false;
                    new ShiftProgress().execute();
                    startHours = Utility.getHoursTime();
                    startMinutes = Utility.getMinutesTime();
                    startString = Integer.toString(Utility.getHoursTime())
                            + ":" + Integer.toString(Utility.getMinutesTime())
                            + " -";

                    String s = "In Shift ";
                    CheckedTextView radio = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
                    radio.setText(s);
                    clicked = true;

                }
            }
        });

        Button addShift = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addShift);
        addShift.setTypeface(tf2);

        // **************** On click listener for adding a shift

        addShift.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (wasShift == true) {

                    changeDateToString(DateInString);

                    DB.open();
                    final Cursor cursor = DB.getAllShifts();
                    startManagingCursor(cursor);
                    cursor.moveToLast();
                    int count = cursor.getPosition();
                    final int position = count + 2;
                    cursor.moveToNext();

                    GregorianCalendar GC = new GregorianCalendar();

                    DB.addToDBTotal(DateInString, "Money: " + madeSoFar,
                            hoursSum, minutesSum,
                            Utility.getDay(GC.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)),
                            position, startString, finishString);

                    DBAdapter.close();
                    wasShift = false;

                    printAny(getApplicationContext(), "Added to Shifts",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                } else {
                    printAny(getApplicationContext(), "Please Check In First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                }

            }
        });

    }



    // **************** METHOD DECLERATIONS ****

    public void viewShifts() {

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main.this, Shifts.class);

        startActivity(myIntent);
    }

    public void changeDateToString(String s) {

        Utility.INSTANCE.setDate(s);
    }

    public void changeDurationToString(String s) {

        Utility.INSTANCE.setDuration(s);
    }

    public void printAny(Context c, CharSequence s, int i) {

        Context context = c;
        CharSequence text = s;
        final int duration = i;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();

    }

        @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.exit:
            System.exit(1);
            DBAdapter.close();

            return true;
        case R.id.view:
            viewShifts();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipe(int direction) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();

        switch (direction) {

        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT:
            intent.setClass(this, Shifts.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT:
            intent.setClass(this, Shifts.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDoubleTap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public class ShiftProgress extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            int count = 0;
            int seconds = 0;
            int minutesTime = 0;
            int minutesCount = 1;

            for (;;) {
                if (seconds % 60 == 0) {
                    minutesTime = count / 60;
                    seconds = 0;

                }

                if (seconds < 10) {

                    formattedSeconds = String.format("%02d", seconds);

                }

                else if (seconds >= 10) {

                    formattedSeconds = String.valueOf(seconds);

                }

                if (minutesTime < 10) {

                    formattedMinutes = String.format("%02d", minutesTime);

                }

                else if (minutesTime >= 10) {

                    formattedMinutes = String.valueOf(minutesTime);

                }

                if (minutesTime % 60 == 0) {
                    hoursCount = minutesCount / 60;
                    minutesTime = 0;

                }
                double sal = 40;
                double SEC = 3600;
                double salper = count * (sal / SEC);
                madeSoFar = String.valueOf(formatter.format(salper));

                try {
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    seconds++;
                    count++;

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (killcheck) {
                    break;

                }
            }

            // int length = count /360;
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Activity state saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
        // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.

        checkedIN = savedInstanceState.getString("checkIN");
        clicked = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("button");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Activity state Restored", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(Bundle b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        b.putString("checkIN", checkedIN);
        b.putBoolean("button", clicked);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Activity state saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("checkIN", checkedIN);
        outState.putBoolean("button", clicked);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Activity state saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        // etc.
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Activity is getting killed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not keep your Async task running in the background when your activity is send to the background. Your activity can be quit at any time so that you wouldn't have a reference to your activity anymore.

Regarding the preservation of state you could have a look at Activity.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()

Comment: Thanks for your comment though I have to let the Async run in the BG. I need the activity to keep doing her thing while the user is able to view other things in other activities.

BTW, I think that the reason it wasn't saved was because, when I swiped left or right - I then started a new activity instead of going back to that same activity that was running before. Does it makes sense?

Comment: You could use a Service to perform your background action and use intents to send your data back to the activity.